# Find the index of the column and the row that contains the same number sequence

Tags: c, arrays

I want to find the index of the column and the row that contains the same number sequence in a 2D array.
for example

```
{2, 3, 2, 6} 
{3, 6, 3, 10} 
{7, 4, 2, 12}
{6, 8, 6, 4}
```

in this example, the program must return the line index 0 and the column index 2
I wrote a program using C language but it doesn't work

```
# include <stdio.h>
        int main(){
            char tab[3][3];
            int simiLgn, simiClm;
        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<3; j++){
                printf("Tableau[%d][%d]=", i, j);
                scanf("%d", &tab[i][j]); 
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<3; j++){
                printf("%d \t", tab[i][j]); 
            }
            printf("\n");
        }


        int fix_lgn = 0;
        int fix_col = 0;
        while (fix_lgn<3){
            while (fix_col<3){
                for (int i=0, j=0; i<3, j<3 ; i++, j++){
                    if(tab[fix_lgn][j] == tab[i][fix_col]){
                        simiLgn = fix_lgn;
                        simiClm = fix_col;
                    }
                    else{
                        simiLgn = -1;
                        simiClm = -1;
                    }
                }
                fix_col++;

        }
        fix_col = 0;
        fix_lgn++;
        }

        printf("ligne index: %d\n", simiLgn);
        printf("colonne index: %d\n", simiClm);

        return 0;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: `i<3, j<3` this doesn't do what you think, switch to `i<3 && j<3`, and here: `tab[fix_lgn, j] ` you want `tab[fix_lgn][j]`

Comment: @KeineLust You are right, but in this loop i does not make a difference because i and j are both always equal.

Comment: @WernerHenze, you are right, anyway the OP should know it

Comment: @WernerHenze @ KeineLust thanks for help i will try to update the code